# Errors when I try to compile old Android Native App

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to compile an old native Android app which was not developed by me, but I'm facing the following errors:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Execution failed for task ':androidLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.3 and when I opened the project for the first time I've asked to update the Gradle plugin:
[image]

How to solve this?

PS: I'm a complete newbie in native Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your gradle, then clean and rebuild the project:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

      aaptOptions {
          cruncherEnabled = false
      }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.0'
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
   }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Solved! I only need to keep the first line `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update your `buildToolsVersion` to `22.2.0`